# cooling system problem throwing water out when its hot

Tags: coolant-reservoir

I am having a problem with my cooling water leaking out through but there's no external leakage could it be that there air in the system because I try to replace the thermostat but still leaking through the radiator cap if it get hot what could it be or what must I do again. its Chevrolet cruise 1.8 2011 model.

Comment: You need to work on the grammar of your question a little more.  Try to rephrase it so it clearer - right now I can't tell what you're asking.  Where is the water leaking?

Comment: Water is leaking but there is no external leakage doesn't make sense. Does that mean the level is going down, but there are not visible leaks? You say you tried to replace the thermostat. Did you or didn't you? There is no try. :-)

Comment: it leaks out through the radiator cap whn it got hot...

Answer (score 1):

Take the time to fill it up with coolant, turn the heat on max, and bleed the air out of the system. A spill free funnel makes it easier.
http://revlimiter.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/DSC_1249.jpg

The radiator cap could be bad.  The cap is probably rated for 15 psi and if that went bad water could leak out.

Comment: my thoughts exactly..